# Embedded Stackviews triggering autolayout error

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview, stackview

I am using a series of embedded stackviews in the storyboard.  I'm getting this error in the console and also noticing jittery scrolling in the table view.

"This system of layout constraints is extremely difficult to optimize, taking 1014 pivots.  Try ensuring your layout is not over-constrained and you have no redundant constraints."

How can I optimize my layout while still taking advantage of the utility of stackviews?

[image]

Comment: Stack Views are great... until they're not. With a layout this straight-forward, I'd suggest simply laying out your labels and adding logical constraints.

Comment: Damn!  Will do!  Thanks @DonMag

Comment: My interface also uses multiple nested stack views, and I just received the same error. Did you ever find a workaround or did you have to scrap all the nesting?

Comment: @djibouti33 yes I just ended up making it a lot less complicated (i.e. less stackviews)